# how to find the inverse

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

[gamma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geqjI.png)

using this equation

$1-\sqrt{1-x^2/c^2}$

where c = 1 and x= 0.0 - 1.0 the speed of c

for example

$1-\sqrt{1-.886^2/1^2}$ = y = 0.5363147619

gives me the y values on the graph. How do I find the inverse? How do find for x inputting the values of y?

Thank you.

Comment: Using the rules of algebra and solving equations ... What have you tried? Remember that
$$
\frac{1}{(1/b)} = b \qquad (b\neq 0)
$$

Comment: You can start by writing $\eta = x/c$ and then
$$
1 - \frac{1}{(1/\sqrt{1-\eta^2})} = 1- \sqrt{1-\eta^2} = y
$$
and then move the terms around.

Comment: Where is an exponential function ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph for $0\le x\le 1$

[image]

For the inverse, note that $$(x,y)\in f\iff (y,x)\in f^{-1}$$therefore the inverse would be found from $$x=1-\sqrt{1-y^2}$$from which we obtain $$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2/c^2}}}$, then $f(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2/c^2}.$

Hence $\sqrt{1-x^2/c^2}=1-f(x)$, thus $1-x^2/c^2=1-2f(x)+f(x)^2.$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: apologies, math was never my strong suit but I will try. Thank you

Comment: sorry I tried. I'm lost